# What category is this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-solver, matrix, linear-programming

My first question, please excuse me if its too basic.

I have a matrix of evenly spaced geographical points; say `10 x 10`, which I will call **seed** points. Each seed point has a lat/long and the spacing can vary.

Then I place $n$ random points on the same matrix. I call these **demand** points.

What algorithm can I use to calculate a variable $n$ seed points which will minimize the distance to all the demand points in the matrix?

The user will decide if he/she needs a single seed or multiple seeds to satisfy all the demand points. If a single seed is selected its similar to an average of the demand points, a centroid. But what if multiple seed points need to be selected, say 2. So the problem becomes, which two seed points if selected would give the minimum distance to all the demand points. Each demand point will connect to a single seed and not both.

[image]

What I would ideally like is this problem identified as a MIP / LP problem, its name given (i.e. "Travelling Salesman"). Then I can go and research how to solve it using a solver. But that is only if it is possible with a solver.

Comment: I believe this is technically an optimization problem. You could go about trying to solve it by computing a centroid of the demand points and then finding the point in the seed points that is closest to this centroid. Given that the seed points aren't time varying, you could stick them in a KDTree and do a nearest neighbor search using the centroid of the demand points to find the optimal seed point.

Comment: @choward thanks for the response, unfortunately I oversimplified the description of my problem. Please see my edit.

Comment: I think it would greatly help if you used formulas to concisely explain what you mean by "calculate a variable $n$ seed points which will minimize the distance to all the demand points in the matrix".

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth unfortunately I do not know the maths notation, but I can draw a picture which I hope will explain it, please see my edit.

Comment: This sounds like a variant of either the [k-nearest neighbor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) or the [k-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) problem.

Comment: @ChristianClason thanks, would those methods give me an optimum result? and could this problem be set up for a LP / MIP solver? (that is what I have been attempting and struggling with).

Comment: They do have some optimality properties (i.e., they minimize distances in some specific way). I'm sure you can set up the problems as nonlinear (not sure about linear) problems, but I believe there exist more efficient specialized algorithms (on which I'm not an expert).

Comment: @لَاإِلٰهَإِلَّاالله I also think, given the added info, you could first use a k-means algorithm to find some optimal k centroids. Then you could use a KD Tree to do a nearest neighbor search, using those k centroids, to find which seeds are the closest to the ideal k centroids. These seeds would be your resulting set. Also, when I looked into k-means, a common formulation uses the L2 norm in the cost function, so this should work for doing the optimization you want. Here's a link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Comment: "Uncapacitated facility location" might give you some useful hits.  If you'd like more specific help here, you should provide information about the size (number of points) of your problem and how big the numbers in your problem are relative to the grid size.

Comment: Sounds like finding a Voronoi Partition with minimum cost. See "Minimum-Cost Load-Balancing Partitions" by Arnov et al. for example. Probably NP-hard...

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a trivial problem to solve for a moderate number $k$ of "stations" (i.e., the subset of seed points that serve the demand points):

- Try $k=1$. For each of your $i=1\ldots N=10^2$ seed points, compute the sum of distances between the demand points and a proposed station at $i$: $D^{(1)}_i=\sum_{\nu=1}^n \|x_{\text{demand},\nu} - x_{\text{seed,i}}\|$. Among all possible station locations, choose the location $i^\ast$ that minimizes $D^{(1)}_i$ and call the distances to the best location $D^{(1)}=D^{(1)}_{i^\ast}=\min_i D^{(1)}_i$.
- Try $k=2$. There are $N(N-1)/2$ possible locations for two stations. Let's say they are at seed points $i,j$. Then compute the sum of distances, $D^{(2)}_{ij}=\sum_{\nu=1}^n \min\left\{\|x_{\text{demand},\nu} - x_{\text{seed,i}}\|,\|x_{\text{demand},\nu} - x_{\text{seed,j}}\|\right\}$. Among these possibilities, select those locations $i^\ast,j^\ast$ that minimizes these distances and call the best distances $D^{(2)}=D^{(2)}_{i^\ast j^\ast}=\min_{i,j} D^{(2)}_{ij}$.
- Repeat for $k=3,4,\ldots$. The effort will quickly grow for larger $k$, but you're probably not interested in the case $k=100$ supply stations.
- Then compare $D^{(1)},D^{(2)},\ldots$ to see which one is smallest, and that is the number of stations you need.

Comment: Thank you. A question I have is, does this method consider the requirement that when there are multiple "stations", each one cannot serve every "demand" point. The relationship is "station" 1 --> * demand points. So there will be a split, one station will take some, and the other will take others, this is the difficult part I think.

Comment: The way I've described it, each demand point will be served by the closest supply station. You may have to modify things if that's not what you want.